# Javascript array of objects to MVC action barely working, but not fully

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a javascript array of objects to a MVC action via ajax; here's my code:

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: rv + "ajxConversation/wrcrgmdisc",
   dataType: "json",
   traditional: true,
   data: JSON.stringify(pllst),
   contentType: "application/json",
   async: true,
   global: false,
   cache: false,
   success: function (d) {
     //Whatever
   }
});
```

MVC:

```
public JsonResult wrcrgmdisc(List<DCConvGmPlayersDisc> pllst)
{
}

[DataContract]
public class DCConvGmPlayersDisc
{        
   [DataMember]
   public string clr = "";

   [DataMember]
   public string tlt = "";

   [DataMember]
   public string fnm = "";

   [DataMember]
   public string lnm = "";
}
```

Now, my problem is that on the MVC side, it seems to receive an array with all items, but they're all having empty properties, not null ones: If I send a JS Array with 5 items, my pllst count on the MVC side is 5, but each properties of each item is empty: on the server side in debug mode, I see pllst[0].clr is an empty string, pllst[0].tlt is empty, etc....

[Here's a screen shot of JS "alert(JSON.stringify(pllst));" to prove you that I'm not passing an empty array:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmmtn.jpg)
sdfsd

[...and one from the server side showing that the received array really has 3 items, but all properties are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDFJg.jpg)

OR

Can someone show me a FUNCTIONNAL way to pass Javascript **arrays of objects** (not arrays of string or arrays of int such as int[] varaible) to MVC Action via Ajax or a link to a page that shows it: I've googled the entire web for a fully functionnal, simple, standard way (this is not standard Ajax: $.get('/controller/MyAction', { vals: arrayOfValues }, function (data) {...} ) of doing it, and I haven't found one, even here on Stackoverflow!!

Thanx

Comment: You need to edit you question to show what `pllst` is

Comment: Yeh. Pictures suck. It's really easy to provide text instead and a whole load easier to follow.

Comment: And you model has only fields, not properties (with `{ get; set; }`) so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class `DCConvGmPlayersDisc` has only fields, not properties so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the values. Change your class to

```
public class DCConvGmPlayersDisc
{        
    public string clr { get; set; }
    public string tlt { get; set; }
    public string fnm { get; set; }
    public string lnm { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That was it: I just changed my fields to properties (sorry for confusing Fields and Properties: University theory is a long way back for me lol!) and now it works fine...thanks Stephen for the quick answer

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to show what `pllst` is Its not acceptable to include images of code and your question will attract a lot of down votes over time if your don't (plus I will remove my down vote)